# Ubiquity of OpenCL compatibility?

Tags: opencl

If I write a desktop application that requires OpenGL and OpenCL (and communication between the two--rendering based on opencl calculations), what are the situations where users will not be able to use it? Are we at the point where OpenCL is pretty much available on all desktops and laptops in the last 3 years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All recent discrete GPUs support OpenCL, as do AMD APUs and CPUs.  All Intel CPUs can be supported using the AMD APP SDK.  Intel's OpenCL SDK has some limits on which CPUs and which Intel GPUs it supports.  Therefore, your application will always be able to fall back to using the CPU if no supported GPUs are available.  I have yet to meet a desktop without OpenGL.  If everything is installed properly then you shouldn't have any problems.

Your biggest problems will come from driver bugs in both OpenCL and OpenGL implementations - my friends and I have seen a lot of this over the years.

Comment: Let's say I have AMD APU with integrated GPU cores, but NO discrete video card. Can I use these GPU cores for calculations (via OpenCL)? If yes, what part of the system will show video on the monitor?

Comment: The GPU cores can be used via OpenCL.  The integrated GPU will continue to render graphics to your screen while it is executing OpenCL code.

Comment: Thanks! Will it be like half of GPU cores for calculations and half of them for video? Or context switching on each core? I suspect it's configurable - am I right?

Comment: If you use device partitioning then I believe you could leave half (or some other fraction) of the GPU cores for video.  Otherwise, during an OpenCL kernel call, the GPU will not respond to graphics API calls.  For short kernel calls, this is not an issue as long as the screen gets to update roughly 30 times per second.  That's also something to keep in mind to avoid Timeout Detection and Recovery on Windows.